# row_number in descending order dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, row-number

I would like to use row_numbers to output a ranking variable in which the row ranked 1 has the highest vote count, and descending:

```
df<-tibble(x=letters[1:4], votes=c(30,55,21,12))
```

If I use row_number I have this output

```
af%>%mutate(rank=row_number(votes))


# A tibble: 4 x 3
  x     votes  rank
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 a        30     3
2 b        55     4
3 c        21     2
4 d        12     1
```

But my desired output for rank would be 2,1,3,4

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use the `rank()` function with a `-` before `votes` indicating the descending order:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(-votes))

  x     votes  rank
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        30     2
2 b        55     1
3 c        21     3
4 d        12     4
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was a simple way with `row_number` but this will do perfectly.